# Swift - Force view to load data after appearing

Tags: ios, swift, performance, load

Heyho,

i got a little problem with two of my view controllers.
They are both collection view controllers.

My problem is, if i click on the button to open the second view it lags and the transition is not liquid. The reason for this lag is the bunch of data the view loads for the collection view(around 400 photos and strings).

Maybe someone of you got a idea how i could defeat this loading inhibition. If you need more information --> just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to fix that is to load you data in a background thread and reload your collection view (in the UI thread) when it's done:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    // load your data here

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // reload your collection view here:
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but i don't get were to use the "load the data here" term in my case. The data is loaded in the collectionView Methods, and i really won't change that(isn't possible at all). And i tried the code in "viewWillAppear", but it still did lag. Its because the collectionView methods are called before the view even appears. Maybe you understand my problem and can help me to use your code right. Thanks :)

Comment: Sry, i mean the data(photos and strings are stored in arrays), they don't have to be loaded. The reason why it don't have a liquid transition is because the collectionView needs so long to insert the data of the arrays. If i open the view once and then again it don't have any lag time.

Comment: Do you load all your data (especially the images) in the "viewDidLoad" or 'viewWillAppear" method? Or in the "cellForItemAtIndexPath"? Where ever you actually load the data, you need to do it in a background thread.

Comment: i fill the arrays for the collectionView in the viewdidLoad method. I solved the problem by making those arrays global and fill them in the app delegate file.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but by doing that, you'll have to wait for your data to load at the app start up. That's fine if that's what you want, but you could also load them when you need them in the view controller (in a background thread), and display a progress view to show the user that you're loading something.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to achieve the required result.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Configure the views 
}
```

On the other hand, you have `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. Find the one which suits you.